# imagebutton not redirecting when site is live

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Ive an asp.net 4.0, c# site,
all the functionality works fine apart from one thing which is doing my head in.
I have 3 image buttons on the masterpage which link to the clients facebook, linkd in and twitter pages,
when I run it on my dev machine (IE 8) the open fine,
when I make the site live (IIS 6) they dontr appear to do anything, no error, no redirect, nothing in the event log.
I was about to bin them and do them from scratch but im wary that I'll install it and the same thing will happen - anything obvious I should check?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you checked whether you missed deploying any external CSS files or images if there are any which effectively causes image buttons to get hidden/unidentifiable?